# Laurent expansion of $1/\sin^2(z)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I am trying to compute the Laurent expression of the function $f(z) = 1/\sin^2(z)$, and I am unable to see where I went wrong. This is my work so far:

By checking WolframAlpha, one sees that the Laurent series does have a principal part (with terms $a_n z^{n}, n<0$), and therefore I expect to get a Laurent series with some negative powers. I am interested in the annulus defined by $\pi < |z| < 2\pi$, and we will need to keep this in mind because trigonometric functions are not bound in the complex plane. What I did is this:

$$\frac{1}{\sin^2(z)} = \frac{1}{1-\cos^2(z)} = (…)$$

Because $|\cos^2(z)|>1$ when $\pi < |z| < 2\pi$, we will need to manipulate the expression a little. Multiplying and dividing the denominator by $\cos^2(z)$, we get:
$$(…) = -\frac{1}{\cos^2(z)}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{\cos^2(z)}} = (…)$$
I was able to calculate the first few terms of $1/\cos(z)$, and as I result I know that $1/\cos^2(z) = 1 + z^2 + \frac{2}{3}z^4 + O(z^6)$. Since we know that for $|w|<1$
$$\frac{1}{1-w} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty w^n$$
Then I arrive at:

$$(…) = -(1+z^2+O(z^4))\cdot (1 + 1+z^2+O(z^4))$$

It is clear that this product will not yield negative powers anywhere. Where did I go wrong? I suspect it is in my assumption about the values that the cosine will take in the annulus, since in the vicinity of the real axis it does take small values. I do not know how to arrive to the correct Laurent series. I have been trying to solve this in many different ways, but I do not get the desired result. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by $\cos^2z>1$ for $\pi< \lvert z\rvert<2\pi$? Certainly $\cos^2z$ is not real on any whole open set of $\Bbb C$; moreover, there are values of $z$ such that $\lvert z\rvert\in(\pi,2\pi)$ and $\cos^2z\le 1$, namely the ones for which $z\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: I meant to refer to $|\cos^2(z)|$, sorry. But you're right about $\cos^2 z$ being less than one in the real line, I just do not know which logic to follow in order to compute the first few terms of this series.

Comment: Perhaps, if we use that $-\frac{d cot z}{dz}=\frac{1}{\sin^2 z}$, so if we remember $\sin z =\sum (-1)^n \frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$ and $\cos z=\sum (-1)^n \frac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!} $we can construct the other, because  $ cot z= \frac{\cos z}{\sin z}$, i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a pole at $z_0$, you can set $w=z-z_0$ so $z=w+z_0$, then letting $g(w)=f(w+z_0)$ you can expand around $w=0$ to make things easier to notate.

Noting first that $\sin^2(z)= \frac{1-\cos(2z)}{2}$, which gives an easy well known series to work with when expanding.

We have that $\sin^2(n\pi)=0$ for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, so $f$ has a pole at each $z_n=n\pi$.
Then letting $w=z-z_n$, we have around $0$ that:

$$\begin{align}
g(w) & = f(z+n\pi) \\
& = 1/\sin^2(z+n\pi) \\
& = \dfrac{2}{1-\cos(2z+2n\pi)} \\
&= \dfrac{2}{1-\cos(2z)} \\
& = \dfrac{2}{1-1+\dfrac{(2z)^2}{2}-\dfrac{(2z)^4}{24}+O(z^6)}\\
& = z^{-2}*\dfrac{1}{1-\dfrac{z^2}{3}+O(z^4)}\\
& = z^{-2}*\sum_{n=0}^\infty(\dfrac{z^2}{3}+O(z^4))^n \\
& = z^{-2}*(1+z^2/3+O(z^4)) \\
& = \dfrac{1}{z^2}+\dfrac{1}{3}+O(z^2)
\end{align}$$

This'll work at least near $n\pi$, but again we'll have issues on whether $\cos(2z)$ will be sufficiently bounded.

Comment: Thanks! This was a really good explanation. I have managed to solve the problem in a different way arriving at the same series. I quite like your solution.